# react handle value change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have  a react code. There is a radio button. When a value is selected, 'handleChange' method is called. The new radio button selected value is correctly printed.

From handlechange, i am unable to pass value to updateCustomerConfiguration . This method will call my editCustomerConfig redux action to send data to back end.  editCustomerConfig  method is not even called.

updateCustomerConfiguration  method console log prints blank value .

I get error 'Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.'

How do i pass in the value to updateCustomerConfiguration  ?

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log("handleChange 2:",event.target.value);
    updateCustomerConfiguration(value);
};

const updateCustomerConfiguration = async () => {
    console.log("updateCustomerConfiguration:"+value);

    let payload = { value };
    const result = await editCustomerConfig(payload);
}



<RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" 
        value={value} onChange={handleChange}
        >
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: const updateCustomerConfiguration = async (value) => {
    console.log("updateCustomerConfiguration:"+value);

    let payload = { value };
    const result = await editCustomerConfig(payload);
}

Comment: strangely doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `async ()` with `async value`
and call `updateCustomerConfiguration(event.target.value);`